# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) When working in swift trying to login to spotify

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, spotify

Code:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  SplitterSwift3
//
//  Created by VideoLabN on 4/8/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 VideoLabN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AWSAuthCore
import AWSMobileClient
import AWSCore


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var auth = SPTAuth()
// Add a AWSMobileClient call in application:open url
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    // called when user signs into spotify. Session data saved into user defaults, then notification posted to call updateAfterFirstLogin in ViewController.swift. Modeled off recommneded auth flow suggested by Spotify documentation


    if auth.canHandle(auth.redirectURL) {
        auth.handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url, callback: { (error, session) in


            if error != nil {
                print("error!")
            }
            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)
            print(sessionData)
            userDefaults.set(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)
        })
        return true
    }

    return false


}

 //Add a AWSMobileClient call in application:didFinishLaunching
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
        application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
        launchOptions)
}

}


//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SplitterSwift3
//
//  Created by VideoLabN on 4/8/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 VideoLabN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SafariServices
import AVFoundation
import AWSAuthCore
import AWSAuthUI


class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate  {

// Variables
var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
var session:SPTSession!

// Initialzed in either updateAfterFirstLogin: (if first time login) or in viewDidLoad (when there is a check for a session object in User Defaults
var player: SPTAudioStreamingController?
var loginUrl: URL?

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var loginSpotify: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loginSplitter: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("test")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setup()
    //NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateAfterFirstLogin, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)
    //self.updateAfterFirstLogin()

}

func setup () {

    // insert redirect your url and client ID below
    let redirectURL = "splitter-app://callback" // put your redirect URL here
    let clientID = "207ce42c908f42e485c540be11720888" // put your client ID here
    auth.redirectURL     = URL(string: redirectURL)
    auth.clientID        = "client id goes here"
    auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope]
    loginUrl = auth.spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()
    //print("test")


}
func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.player == nil {
        self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.player!.delegate = self
        try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
    }
}
@objc func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
    loginSpotify.isHidden = true
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
        let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
        let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
        self.session = firstTimeSession
        initializePlayer(authSession: session)
    }
}







func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
    // after a user authenticates a session, the SPTAudioStreamingController is then initialized and this method called
    print("logged in")
//        
self.player?.playSpotifyURI("spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp", 
startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
//            if (error != nil) {
//                print("playing!")
//            }
//
//        })

    }
@IBAction func spotifyButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: loginUrl!)
    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //UIApplication.shared.open(loginUrl!, options: [:])


}

}
```

The application compiles just fine and launches on the simulator IPhone. The button to login to Spotify works, and opens a Safari instance prompting the user to login to Spotify.

Once the user has logged in, it then asks for permissions. Once the user accepts the permissions, the app crashes on line 16 of the appDelegate class with this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

I have read up on this online and people are saying it is the equivalent to a null pointer exception, but I cannot find what is causing this error. Can anyone find the error?

Edit: Thanks to those that have responded! Here is my console output:

> objc[19082]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace
>   (0x12b9174d0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
>   (0x12aa65e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   test 2018-04-15 13:33:50.341600-0400 SplitterSwift3[19082:1059086]
>   [AXRun-PID] Client requesting unsuspension of PID:-1 Name:
>   2018-04-15 13:33:50.441522-0400 SplitterSwift3[19082:1058985] [MC]
>   System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   path is
>   /Users/videolabn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CEC32A65-63E0-4499-AB25-6BD13A7AE013/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-04-15 13:33:50.442782-0400 SplitterSwift3[19082:1058985] [MC]
>   Reading from private effective user settings. 2018-04-15
>   13:33:50.536744-0400 SplitterSwift3[19082:1058985] [App] if we're in
>   the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due
>   to CA restriction (lldb)

Comment: On which line does it stop if you set an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409199/2895075)?

Comment: Do you have a full crash log in console? Because I see a few "!" (force unwapping) that could causes this issue or by anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Larme! Im a noob, how do I find the full crash log?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @MichaelHulet! I set a general exception breakpoint but I still get the same error on the same line! Am I doing something wrong or am I just getting the same error?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what line 16 is. Count from the top of the file, count from the start of the method, include blank lines, don't include blank lines, include comments, don't include comments when counting.... What is line 16?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to properly format and proofread your questions. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that @Gruntcakes! Line 16 is the class declaration. I was counting everything including comments and line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

The `UIApplicationDelegate` function [`application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application) was deprecated in iOS 10.

As of iOS 11.3 it seems that apps using this function will crash when it is invoked.  The solution is is to use the replacement [`application(_:open:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) instead.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if auth.canHandle(auth.redirectURL) {
        auth.handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url, callback: { (error, session) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error!")
            }
            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)
            print(sessionData)
            userDefaults.set(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)
        })
        return true
    }
    return false  
}
```

Also, there is no need to call `synchronize` for `UserDefaults`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I implemented this change and instead of getting an error, when I press okay on the spotify premission screen nothing happens. It just stops. The app does not crash however, so it may be a problem with how I implemented the spotify api.

Comment: Does it return to your app?  Does your app do something when the `loginSuccessfull` notification is posted? - check the spelling of the notification name you are observing; there is a double l at the end of the notification you are posting. It is better to create notification names in one place and refer to them rather than use a literal string where you could have inconsistencies.